# error when using nginx and php-cgi on Windows: No input file specified

Tags: windows, php, nginx, fastcgi

I get the above error when using nginx and php-cgi on Windows. This is my nginx configuration:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  include mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  sendfile on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;

  server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name localhost;
    charset utf-8;
    root ..\www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      root ..\www;
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
      access_log off;
      log_not_found off;
      deny all;
    }

    location / {

      if (!-e $request_filename) {
          rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
      }

    }

  }

}
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with it?

Edit: here's a request log.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Apr/2012:00:04:35 +0100] "GET /hi.php HTTP/1.1" 404 36 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20120428 Firefox/15.0a1"
```

Comment: Could you enable log and post a logged request? Also, while likely irrelevant, which version of Windows are you running this on?

Comment: Added log to the question. And running Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 x64

Comment: Eh, I just realized the request log doesn't tell much, error log would be better. Did you perhaps try using full path in the .php location for root? i.e. c:/nginx/www

Comment: Nothing logs in the error file. And just tried your suggestion, now I get a nginx 404 page.

Answer (score 3):

[Please, read the documentation carefully](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html)

> Paths in a configuration file must be specified in UNIX-style using
>   forward slashes:
>
> ```
> access_log   logs/site.log;
> root         C:/web/html;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try using forward slashes `/` instead of backslashes `\` in your root directives.

Also, I don't think you need a root directive in your `location ~ \.php$ {` block.

Answer (score 0):

> Nothing logs in the error file. And just tried your suggestion, now I get a nginx 404 page.

1. Remove "try_files $uri =404;" from "location ~ .php$ { }".
2. Add "root c:/nginx/www;" (or right path) to "location / {}".
3. "if (!-e $request_filename) {}" much better replace to try_files.